# CSE vs GVN in compiler optimization theory

Tags: compiler-construction

I get one question when I read Lecture 11, [Common Subexpression Elimination, of Advanced Compilers](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/classes/cmpsci710-spring2004/) course of umass amherst.

The question is, on page 12 in Lecture 11, it illustrates that value numbering can't eliminate all subexpressions.

```
    read(i);
    l = 2*i;
    if(i > 0) goto L1;
    j = 2*i;
    goto L2;
L1: k = 2*i;
L2:
```

The explanation is: l’s value is not always equal to j’s or k’s value

What's puzzled me is, all (l / j / k)'s values depend on 2*i ,  i's value numbering should be the same in all basic blocks as there's no any assignment or re-definition for i in exampled code snippet.  Is it correct?

If it's correct, 2*i will get the same value numbering too and the redundant 2*i  computations for j and k can be eliminated successfully.

Do I make any mistake for the illustration?  please help me to address it if you found.

Comment: This seems like a good question based on what I know of the CSE pass in GCC. I think the problem is, I don't see a lot of folks with the knowledge you need patrolling Stack Overflow. You might consider asking on [GCC Help](https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html) mailing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in both assumptions. The value number for `i` and subsequently the value number for `2*i` will be the same in the entire function following `read(i)`. Thus the computation of `2*i` is redundant when assigning `j` and `k`, it could be replaced with `l` in both cases.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking... what compiler do you work on?

Comment: @jww The IAR compiler.